# Genexus - How to Write String Literals?

Tags: string, string-literals, genexus

We have procedures that initialize our database triggers/functions, so they have the SQL commands inserted on varchar variables as strings in plain code, like the following example:

[image]

My questions is:

- Is there any way in Genexus to write multiline strings? like [c# literal strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) using `@`, or with the recent java 13 [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html) using triple double quotes `""" multilineText """`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeneXus currently has no support for multiline.
You are doing it the correct way, based on the code you shared.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a string to a SQL sentence (like this: `|`) and then do a `replace` before executing the SQL.

```
&NewLine = NewLine()

&SQL = &SQL.Replace('|',&newLine())
```

Or using a **regular expression**.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is an English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577). Please translate your answer to English or participate on [pt.so].